# Error "font not found" when using Sanskrit 2003

Tags: fonts

Here is the beginning of my `.tex` file

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\setsansfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\setmonofont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
```

but when I compile, I get following error:

```
\font\dev="Sanskrit 2003:script=deva" at 12pt\dev
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!! The font "Sanskrit 2003" cannot be found.
!! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!! For immediate help type H<return>.
!...............................................
 ...ainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! you may want to read the [Markdown formating help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for further questions.

Comment: Do you actually have the font installed? Does the minimal example posted by @murugan work for you?  If it does, then there is something else going on with your document but you don't give us enough information.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is what you want

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\newfontfamily\sanskrit[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\begin{document}
The main text is in English, and you can add sanskrit quote...
\begin{quotation}\sanskrit
सर्वधर्मान् परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्र्ज
अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

[image: sans1]

Comment: Instead of adding a second answer you should just edit your previous answer (or now that you've added this answer you can delete the previous one).

Comment: I mentioned the possibilities of creating  text in sanskrit

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\dn{\catcode`\~=12
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,%
Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Sanskrit 2003}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
 \begin{document}
 {\dn
namastu"n+ga"sira"scumbicandracaamaracaarave |\\
trailokyanagaraarambhamuulas+tambhaaya "sambhave || 1 ||\\
haraka.n.thagrahaanandamiilitaak.sii.m namaamyumaam |\\
kaalakuu.tavi.saspar"sajaatamuurcchaagamaamiva || 2 ||}
\end{document}
```

[image: sans]

Comment: It's unlikely that this is a solution to the problem. Adding the Veltuis mapping won't make the missing font somehow appear (as your answer implies). There are other problems with this answer too. First you shouldn't use `\fontspec` in a macro like this. Instead you should use `\newfontfamily` and then use the font command that creates. And there's really no need to enter the text in the Veltuis transliteration: you can enter it directly.